# Confusion in understanding classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I'm confused in understanding, how java interpretor and java compiler searches for all the necessary jar files it requires from environment variables. As I have only set the set path variable for JDK directory, but I've not set any variable to search for any class libraries, which jvm requires. How can it search those important jar files?

Comment: What class libraries do you mean? Which jvm requires? Do you mean JVM jars? Those are already on classpath, by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which jar files are you talking about? Java already knows about the jar files it "owns" (such as rt.jar) - you don't have to tell it about them explicitly. This is known as the [bootclasspath](http://www.tedneward.com/files/Papers/BootClasspath/index.html) - you can override it, but usually you don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding of how classes are found and loaded by JVM read [How Classes are Found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html).

Comment: +1, but more recently: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for pointing that out.

Didn't notice that it was for 1.3.  :(  But most of the concepts still hold true thanks to Java's backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

CLASSPATH is an enviromental variable is like the path file (which helps windows to find executables). It lists a set of all places the JVM looks for classes. You can also give the classpath on the command line when starting the jvm and java compiler