# Java jar files without libraries

Tags: java, jar

I've been wondering about this for a while.
How do some jar files work without their required libraries compressed inside them or in the same directory as them?
For example, bukkit plugins. Every time i make one, i include the bukkit library. But whe nthe jar file is made, there is no trace of the bukkit library inside the jar file.

Comment: I dont know anything about Bukkit but by looking at their website the Bukkit libraries are likely deployed with the Minecraft server. Your plugin wont need (and probably should not have) the libraries with it.

Answer (score 2):

there is a similar question here [Confusion in understanding classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198257/confusion-in-understanding-classpath).
It's all in understanding what the CLASSPATH is and how it works, try to take a look at this page that explains how the classes are "searched"/loaded
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

.

Comment: @FirstWorldAnarchy if this answer was correct, mark it so :)

Answer (score 0):

The classpath of the Java interpreter determines what libraries it will load.  This is set when Java starts.

Or rather, that would be the generic answer.  In the case of your addon, it's being loaded **from** Bukkit, so Bukkit/Minecraft is already loaded in memory.